# creating a table in the database with a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error whenever I try to create my table:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> hehi VARCHAR NOT NULL,
> adds VARCHAR NOT NULL,
> aob VA...' at line 3

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE patients (
    patientId int NOT NULL,
    problem VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    hehi VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    adds VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    aob VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (patientID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_userspatients FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the lengths of your VARCHARs,
e.g. if the column problem is supposed to hold 255 characters max.:

```
problem VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/ for more info

**Update:**
As P.salmon mentioned in the comments, your foreign key definition should be updated to

```
CONSTRAINT FK_userspatients FOREIGN KEY (patientId)
```

If `patientId` refers to the corresponding field `user_id` of table `users`.

Comment: True but also user_id does not exist in table patients. Perhaps op meant FOREIGN KEY (patientid)?